# Dictionary containing words from a text file as keys with a list of all the next words as values

Tags: python, list, file, dictionary

I'm having trouble figuring the logic behind this.

1.) First I read a text file stripped of punctuations and white space from this text file:

```
The sun is bright & the moon glows.
The dog barks while the cat meows.
My dog is dark, dark as crows.
```

2.) After reading this text file, I'm suppose to have a dictionary with a word as the key, and the very NEXT word as the value, like so:

```
{'the':['sun','moon','dog','cat'], 'sun':['is'], 'is':['bright','dark'], 'moon':['glows'],'glows':['the'], 
 'dog':['barks','is'], 'barks':['while'],'while':['the'], 'cat':['meows'],'meows':['my'], 'my':['dog'], 
 'dark':['dark','as'], 'as':['crows'], 
 'bright':['the'], 'crows':[]}
```

The last two items are special cases. `"crows"` has an empty list because it is the last word in the text file.

I'm not sure about the logic behind this but I can't seem to wrap my head around this.

My first approach was creating a giant list with all the words and picking and pulling from the list to form several smaller lists.

Answer (score 1):

you can chain some strings transforms to get rid of the punctuation, then split the string after converting to lowercase (`The` vs `the`).

Then, interleave the list of words with a shifted copy of the same list and iterate over it.

Append the value to the dictionary element so key is the current word, and value is the list of the words that follow. Problem is `crows` is absent from the list. So add the last word manually.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import string

s = "The sun is bright & the moon glows. The dog barks while the cat meows. My dog is dark, dark as crows."
s = s.translate({ord(x):None for x in string.punctuation}).lower().split()

c = defaultdict(list)

for cw,nw in zip(s,s[1:]):
    c[cw].append(nw)

c[s[-1]] = []  # last word of the sentence, special case
print(c)
```

results in:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'is': ['bright', 'dark'], 'moon': ['glows'],
 'cat': ['meows'], 'glows': ['the'], 'meows': ['my'], 'crows': [], 
'bright': ['the'], 'while': ['the'], 'the': ['sun', 'moon', 'dog','cat'],  
'as': ['crows'], 'dog': ['barks', 'is'], 'sun': ['is'], 'my':     
['dog'], 'dark': ['dark', 'as'], 'barks': ['while']})
```

Comment: looked like homework but was a cool problem. Not sure that teacher believes student wrote that like this anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

You can read in a file using `open` and `.read`:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    astr = f.read()
```

First you need to normalize your input. That means replacing the characters you want to ignore and removing bad characters:

```
# lowercase the string
astr = astr.lower()

# remove to-be-ignored characters
for badchar in '&,.':
    astr = astr.replace(badchar, '')
```

The next step is to split the input by whitespaces Then get the words and the next one and append it to the dictionary.

```
result = {}

words = astr.split()
# only iterate until length - 1 because the last word in each 
# sentence has no next word.
for i in range(len(words) - 1):
    result.setdefault(words[i], []).append(words[i+1])
result.setdefault(words[-1], [])
```

Which gives:

```
print(result)
{'as': ['crows'],
 'barks': ['while'],
 'bright': ['the'],
 'cat': ['meows'],
 'crows': [],
 'dark': ['dark', 'as'],
 'dog': ['barks', 'is'],
 'glows': ['the'],
 'is': ['bright', 'dark'],
 'meows': ['my'],
 'moon': ['glows'],
 'my': ['dog'],
 'sun': ['is'],
 'the': ['sun', 'moon', 'dog', 'cat'],
 'while': ['the']}
```